# DAX: Get distinctcount from other table based on value in current table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling with DAX, and want to complete the simple task of counting the number of games hosted by a given player (one table) based on the distinct number of rows in another table (game_instance).

Tables:

```
game_instance (id, owner_id, x, y, z)
player (id, x, y, z)
```

My Measure is as such:

```
Hosted Games = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(game_instance[id]), FILTER(game_instance, game_instance[owner_id] = [id]))
```

I'm getting blank, but I know this not to be true, what is wrong with this measure.

I cannot create a relationship, as there is already a chain relationship, so powerbi will not allow me to make a direct one.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the DAX measure you posted is that the [id] is referring to the game_instance[id] and not to the player[id].

In order to get a correct result it's needed to save the current player id to a variable to be used later in the filter iteration. To make the measure work also for the totals, a SUMX can be added over the player[id] in the current selection (this means just one when the player is selected on the row, or all the players for the total)

This measure might work

```
Hosted Games =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( player[id] ),
    VAR CurrentPlayerID = player[id]
    RETURN
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( game_instance[id] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( game_instance ), game_instance[owner_id] = CurrentPlayerID )
        )
)
```